# how to use a variable in the name of another variable in C++

Tags: c++

I'm using a struct like below:

```
struct Employee{  
string id;  
string name;  
string f_name;  
string password;  
};
```

I wanna have a for loop and every time that I increment i I want to make an object from my struct like this:

```
for(int i= 0; i<5; i++){  
struct Employee Emp(i) = {"12345", "Naser", "Sadeghi", "12345"};  
}
```

All I want is to have objects which are name differently by adding i's value to the end of their names every time like Emp1.

Comment: You can't do this. If you tell up what you are trying to accomplish with this, we might be able to help.

Comment: Look up `array` and `std::vector`.

Comment: You cannot do this in C++; certain interpreted languages provide this functionality. Why do you need uniquely named variables in the `for` loop body anyway? A new variable will be created at the start of each iteration, it's not like you'll get name conflicts.

Comment: You should use macro Concatenation. check this. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html

Comment: @ManthanTilva No, the value of `i` is only known at runtime; macro concatenation would just give you `Empi` in this case.

Comment: @szczurcio yup. Understood. I am also thinking on same line. Thanks to highlight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ doesn't have exact functionality that you ask for. For keepings things together you need to use arrays or other containers. Then, for access you have to use indexers.

Below is working solution for you question (also [here](http://ideone.com/14hcPh)):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Employee {
    std::string id;
    std::string name;
    std::string f_name;
    std::string password;
};

int main() {

    std::vector<Employee> employees; // vector for keeping elements together

    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        // push_back adds new element in the end
        employees.push_back(Employee{ "12345", "Naser", "Sadeghi", "12345" });
    }
    std::cout << employees.size() << std::endl; // 5 returns how many elements do you have.
    std::cout << employees[0].name; // you access name field of first element (counting starts from 0)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It fixed my problem.